# ERROR: cannot resolve this binary! in gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

> for the module "lib-one" goes like this. It implements some binaries then I publish it locally.

```
//: lib-one/build.gradle.kts

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:3.2.3"))
    listOf(
        "", "-assimp", "-openal",
        "-opengl"
    ).map { lib ->
        implementation("org.lwjgl:lwjgl$lib")
        runtimeOnly("org.lwjgl", "lwjgl$lib", classifier = LWJGL.lwjglNatives)
    }
}


publishing {
    publications {
        register<MavenPublication>("lib-one-maven") {
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            setUrl(System.getProperty("url.repo.local.snapshot"))
        }
    }
}
```

> In here this module depend in module "lib-one" but this give me an ordeal "could not resolve on this binary"

```
//: lib-two/build.gradle.kts
repositories {
    maven {
        setUrl(System.getProperty("url.repo.local.snapshot"))
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation("com.demo:lib-one:0.0.1") // HERE! ERROR: could not resolve!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I did found the problem and it is inside of my "settings.gradle". The problem is the incorrect order of the repositories. see here for more info: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#obtaining_module_metadata

```
// this is the incorrect way for my build cuz while the subprojects are 
// applying the next repo.
// settings.gradle.kts
dependencyResolutionManagement {
      repositories.mavenCentral()
}
```